# How do I parse an "id" to a class object from a range function variable during instantiation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

Have spent most of the morning on this one and have to admit that I'm stuck.

I have a task where the core problem is to create a lot of objects, which each have an identifier which should be callable from a function. - By concept this should be similar to the SQL statement

"Select *id* from *all objects* where *id > some integer*;".

The main-function below contains the loop that generates the id's. Next the objects should be created, with the id obtained from the range variable "i". I have looked at using [super](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#super) but can't see the lines that connect the dots. Do you have a good advice on this?

```
class aContainer(self, n):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.id = n
        #self.contains=[]

class create_object(n):
    # Completely blank 

def main()
    for i in range(10):
        create_object(i) # i is the id-tag of the object.
    # next: print list of object.id's

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Deborah" solved the problem as follows in another forum:

If the IDs are unique,
storing a mapping from id to the actual object as a dictionary gives you a
fast (essentially O(1)) lookup. You can either store this externally (as
in the code above) or within the class as part of its interface:

```
>>> class Foo:
    instances = {}
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        Foo.instances[id] = self # or self.instances[id], if you prefer

>>> for i in range(6): # Notice range expression used here!
    Foo(i)

<__main__.Foo object at 0x980a40c>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x981c16c>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x980ed6c>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x980eeac>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x9819f4c>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x9819b0c>
>>> Foo.instances
{0: <__main__.Foo object at 0x980a40c>, 1: <__main__.Foo object at 0x981c16c>, 2: <__main__.Foo object at 0x980ed6c>, 3: <__main__.Foo object at 0x980eeac>, 4: <__main__.Foo object at 0x9819f4c>, 5: <__main__.Foo object at 0x9819b0c>}
```

(and remember not to call Foo(id) directly unless you know the ID is new!)

(You can also do this as a static method, but I'm out of date on how to
declare those... It would be neater, though)

Finally, if you don't care what the actual ID value is, then you can use
id(self), which is guaranteed unique, and not have to pass an ID in in the
first place.

Answer (score 0):

**Not sure why you'd want to do this, but...**

You could adapt something like the following (not this uses a `dict` not a `list`)...:

```
from itertools import count
next_id = count(0)

id_to_object = {}

class blah(object):
    pass

for i in xrange(10):
    id_to_object[next(next_id)] = blah()

for i in xrange(25):
    id_to_object[next(next_id)] = blah()

for k, v in id_to_object.iteritems():
    if k > 5:
        print v
```

Or using a list..., every time you create a *new* object...

```
your_list.append(blah())
```

Then you could do `your_list[5:15]` to get a group of objects.

Comment: Jon, I am very happy with lists and dictionaries, but that is not the case required here. The wider aspects of the code above requires the recursive usage of classes which lists do not permit. So, though your proposed idea is cute, it doesn't solve the problem (or I am not getting the point...?).

Comment: Well, TBH - I'm a little puzzled why you can't just pass the objects around themselves... Also, it's only now you mention *recursive* (admittedly there are some subtle hints in the OP), but maybe it'll be worth clarifying that so others don't think what I thought and I'll leave this here so people know